# How to use a KeyListener and an input handler together?

Tags: java, input

The following class implements a `KeyListener`, and `handleInput()` method gets called in an endless loop.

```
public final class PlayerInput implements KeyboardInputHandler{

  public static final int INVERTED_AXIS = 0;
  public static final int NORMAL_AXIS = 1;

  private Sprite sprite;

  private int axisMode_x=NORMAL_AXIS;
  private int axisMode_y=NORMAL_AXIS;

  private boolean left;
  private boolean right;
  private boolean down; 
  private boolean jumping;
  private boolean doubleJump;

  private int jumpCounter=0;
  private boolean stopLeft;
  private boolean stopRight;
  private boolean stopJumping;
  private boolean stopDoubleJump;

  public PlayerInput(Sprite sprite){

    this.sprite=sprite;     
  }

  public void setAxisMode_x(int axisMode_x) {

    this.axisMode_x = axisMode_x;
  }

  public void setAxisMode_y(int axisMode_y) {

    this.axisMode_y = axisMode_y;
  }

  public void handleInput(){

    if (left){

      if (axisMode_x==INVERTED_AXIS) sprite.setPos_x(sprite.getPos_x()+sprite.getSpeed_x()); 
      else sprite.setPos_x(sprite.getPos_x()-sprite.getSpeed_x());  
    }
    else if (right){

      if (axisMode_x==INVERTED_AXIS) sprite.setPos_x(sprite.getPos_x()-sprite.getSpeed_x()); 
      else sprite.setPos_x(sprite.getPos_x()+sprite.getSpeed_x());
    }
    else{

      sprite.goingLeft(false);
      sprite.goingRight(false);
    }

    if (jumping && sprite.collidedDown){

      sprite.addAction(new JumpingAction());
    }
    else sprite.goingUp(false);
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {      

    switch (e.getKeyCode()){

    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

      right=false;
      left=true;
      e.consume();
    break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

      left=false;
      right=true;
      e.consume();
    break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
      jumping=true;
      e.consume();
    break;
    }
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    switch (e.getKeyCode()){

    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

      left=false;
      e.consume();
    break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

      right=false;
      e.consume();
    break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
      jumping=false;
    break;
    }
  }
}
```

If I want the player to jump, I need to press <kbd>Space</kbd> and then release it... But what if my "jumping" variable checking comes right after my `keyReleased` method?

Is there a way to synchronize these two pieces of code?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can't you just move the "jumping = false;" from the keyReleased method to the if(jumping &&sprite.collidedDown) block?

Answer (score 1):

With this current piece of code, only way I can think about is checking `Press`, then `jumping` and finally `Release`, but this is so weird and makes code so coupled that I think it's not even bad as a solution, it's even worse.

First of all, It's nearly unlikely for a human to press and release a key in 1 frame (talking about a normal fps rate), so it shouldn't be a problem, although it's true it's still a possibility. That said, I would make a **list of events** in each frame, and then I'd check that list from the function **handleInput** or, even more flexible code, (if your architecture allows you to) make a function like:

```
void ManageEvents() {
    foreach (Event ev in eventsList) {
        entity.HandleEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

This way, you would get both **`Press`** and **`Release`** in the same frame, so each element (I mean, the character and the logic which sets `jumping`) would get them for their logic, although you of course loose performance.

I don't know if it's clear enough, if it isn't please add a comment and I'll expand it.

---

EDIT: To help figuring out how to code this list, I'll give a brief example. Please note that I'm currently C++ developer and I haven't used Java for too much time now.

Let's imagine (I can't get your architecture from this piece of code, but I think this example will be self explanatory) you have something similar to the following, ignoring how you fill the list.

---

**InputManager.h**

```
class CInputManager {
    public:
        ...
        void ManageEvents();
    private:
        std::vector<Event *> m_events;
        std::vector<IObserver *> m_observers;
        ...
}
```

---

**InputManager.cpp**

```
void CInputManager::ManageEvents() {
    for (std::vector<Event *>::iterator itrEv = m_events.begin();
            itrEv != m_events.end(); ++itrEv) {
        //we iterate over the list of events
        for (std::vector<IObserver *>::iterator itrOb = m_observers.begin();
                itrOb != m_observers.end(); ++itrOb) {
            (*itrOb)->ManageEvent((*itrEv)); //we send each event to every observer
        }
    }
```

This way, what we do is:

1. Fill events list for each frame.
2. Iterate over the whole list of events.
3. Send every event to all observers.
4. Each observer decides if this event matters or not for itself.

NOTE: Remember you should clean events list after sending events to all observers (each frame).

Here, observers would be any class implementing the interface `IObserver`, entities, controls, buttons... whatever you want.

Note that there are too many optimizations and application-dependent things to have in mind.

I leave here links to a project I'm currently developing, consisting on an InputManager with functionality similar to what you're currently trying. Important files are [InputManager.cpp](https://github.com/jjimenezg93/InputManager/blob/master/src/inputmanager.cpp) and [InputManager.h](https://github.com/jjimenezg93/InputManager/blob/master/include/inputmanager.h). Actually, the code I posted is a simplified version of it, so you could take a look at it if you want a complete version.

Hope your problem is solved now.

Comment: I like the solution you suggested, but i still not figure out how to make this list of events... I tried something like your solution but it seemed strange for me to implement it...

now my game structure has changed so i will try it again with this new solution..

That said, if you would like to better explain your solution, it would be very kind of you since it would give me new advices on how to solve this "1% probability" problem...

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi answer has been updated with an example and links to my own InputManager, which I think that could be useful for you. If you have any other question, ask it. When you're done, please mark the answer as accepted if it is.

Comment: Have a read of the [command pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html).